# adf mapping parameters to json file keeping type

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My goal is to save to a json file, the parameters passed in a Pipeline.
I added the parameter to the pipeline
[image]
And with a copy activity I'm trying to save the value to a json (in a blob storage). The problem is that I can save as string in a json, but I cannot as integer
[image]

Using dynamic content @int(pipeline.parameters...) doesn't work.
Is it possible to save in an integer format?

thanks

I tried to cast as dynamic content and also importing the schema from mapping schema, the type is still a string

Answer (score 0):

I tried same scenario and getting same error as `Expression of type int dose not match the field value`.

**Even we provided direct value int in additional column it is taking it as string.**

The work around is to use dataflow with derived column and data flow parameter and pipeline parameter as shown below:

- First create pipeline parameter with `integer` type.
  [image]
- Create data flow and add source file to it then take derived column and create column and give value as parameter1.
  [image]
  Click on `Open expression builder` >> parameters >>create new.
  [image]
  Give name to parameter as **parameter1** and type as `integer` and click on create.
  [image]
- Then come back to pipeline cand click on dataflow activity >> Parameters >> click on dynamic expression below value box >> select `Pipeline expression` and pass the pipeline parameter which we created.
  [image]

**OUTPUT**

Taking as `int`
[image]